# npm start error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\System32\robinhood\node_modules\.cache'

Tags: create-react-app

I ran `npx create-react-app robinhood` in VS Code, I opened the project and then ran `npm start`. The screen displays correctly for a moment and then leads to the following error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFES7.png)

[VS compile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGnKk.png)

The npm version is 7.24.0

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by allowing Full Control to the Users group:
[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLKXn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your working directory is in System32 which is a windows system folder. You should put all your code in a folder in a more suitable location.